# Why does Thundebird use ≈ 100 % CPU when transferring mails between different IMAP accounts (as well as other tasks)?

Tags: email, cpu, thunderbird, imap

Thunderbird frequently uses 90-100 % CPU on my modern machines when doing I/O-tasks, like checking mail or, what I have done a lot recently: transferring mail from IMAP account A to IMAP account B.

When checking mail the spike is temporary and you don't really notice unless you look specifically at it, but when you transfer 100 MB of mails it takes some time and therefore the fans have time to spin up so it very noticeable.

I remember that not even Eudora, that I used on a Mac SE/30 and classic MacOS, used so much CPU. And today the network stack is much more stable and you have a CPU that is maybe a million time faster¹. Downloading e-mail isn't exactly FTP where you can max out your network connection (I have 1 Gb and AX-WiFi so I get a couple of hundred Mb but e-mail seems to download at, at the best, 10 % of that speed).

**Why is Thundebird using so much CPU???**

¹ If the CPU capacity has increased with 73 % per year for 25 years that is approximately 1 million.

Comment: Try disabling Indexing before moving the messages and re-enable later to see if it helps.

Comment: Typically the number of Emails is high because each is pretty small. As each mail has to be individually processed (get the mail, and then save the mail) the network speed is low because most of the time Thunderbird is waiting for the mail server to finish the current action. The network bandwidth only matters when it comes to copying larger emails.